# When did iPhone add inline support for HTML 5 audio? (No Quicktime)

Tags: iphone, html, mobile-safari, html5-audio

I noticed yesterday that I am able to play HTML5 audio on my iPhone now without it launching Quicktime. This is super exciting and opens up a world of possibilities for iPhone + Web + Audio.

However, I tried the same technique on an iOS 3.0 device and it doesn't seem to be supported. Somewhere between 4.2 and 3.0 this feature set must have been added, but I haven't been able to track down what version it was updated in.

Does anyone know? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it was made available with 4.0. I worked on a project that depended on it and from what I know it only supports progressive downloading. That means the server has to support rpeat requests for chunks of the audio.

Comment: Interesting, the example project I tried it in doesn't allow progressive, but it does explicitly send a header specifying that it doesn't accept byte-range requests.

Comment: There's a quick reference here as well, but it doesn't make mention of this exact change. Only HTML5 as a whole in 3.0. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_version_history